# push объекта перезаписывает массив

Tags: javascript

вопрос следующий, есть простая форма с одним selectom и 2 input, при нажатии на "Отправить", данные формируются в объект и пушатся в массив, который изначально пустой, при первой отправке объект запушился в массив, при последующих массив перезаписывается, в чём проблема? Вот пример кода ` $('.form_btn').click(function (e) {

```
    e.preventDefault();

    let results = [];

    const select = $('#select');
    const name = $('#name');
    const surname = $('#surname');

    const selectedIndex = select[0].options.selectedIndex;
    const selectedValue = select[0].options[selectedIndex].value;
    const selectedValueNumber = Number(selectedValue);

    const nameValue = name[0].value;
    const surnameValue = surname[0].value;

    class Object {
        constructor(options) {
            this.id = options.id,
                this.name = options.name,
                this.surname = options.surname;
        }
    }


    results.push(new Object({
        id: selectedValueNumber,
        name: nameValue,
        surname: surnameValue
    }))`
```

Comment: Это не `push` перезаписывает массив. Он же у вас локальный, внутри функции. Функция вызывается — внутри создаётся новый массив: `let results = [];`. Вынесите объявление/инициализацию массива куда-нибудь за пределы функции.

Comment: Действительно, не подумал об этом, спасибо